# Can Zk-SNARKs verify the results of turing-complete computations?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

My understanding is that Zk-SNARKs (and zero-knowledge proofs in general) can be used to prove that a polynomial-time computation has a certain output, while keeping one or more of the inputs to that computation hidden.

For example, say you have a string *h* which is the output of a fixed hash function. If you know an input *x* which hashes to *h*, you could use a Zk-SNARK to prove you know *x* in zero knowledge (i.e. without revealing *x*). Equivalently, given a verification function like this:

```
verify(x,h):
    return hash(x) == h
```

you're essentially proving that you know inputs to `verify` which make it return *true*, without revealing all of those inputs.

So, here's my question. Suppose you have a secret poly-time, single-argument function *f*. Given a public input *x* and a public output *y*, could you use a Zk-SNARK to prove in zero knowledge that *f(x)=y*? I.e., given the function

```
verify(f,x,y):
    return f(x) == y
```

could you still construct a proof showing that `verify` returns *true* while keeping *f* secret? The difference between this situation and the above one is that now you're proving something about a `verify` function that is itself running an arbitrary function, rather than one which simply does some fixed calculations to check things--and this seems like a pretty significant difference to me.

It seems like this should be possible in theory, because if *f* is poly-time then *f(x)=y* is still an NP statement (although I may be wrong about that)--but I'm wondering if it's possible in practice with today's Zk-SNARKs.

The way I phrased my question, I guess knowledge of such a function is trivial, because if the prover knew *y* in advance, they could just define *f* to return *y*. So to make things more interesting, you could imagine a situation where the prover commits to *f* in advance, and the proof is expanded to verify that the *f* used to compute *y* matches the commitment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Express $f$ as a (say, Boolean) circuit. If $f$ is poly-time it will have a number of gates that is polynomial in the input size. A *universal circuit* $U$ is a Boolean circuit that evaluates any circuit up to bounded size (see e.g. [this eprint from 2017 by Günther, Kiss and Schneider](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/798.pdf)). The input to $U$ will be bits representing the structure of the circuit of $f$. Since $U$ is just another Boolean circuit, it can also be represented as a QAP as in [the Pinocchio paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/279.pdf), or whatever the zk-SNARK uses.